# How do I navigate to a Fragment destination within a different Activity?

Tags: android, android-navigation, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

This is my first attempt at using AndroidX navigation component and I can't seem to find an answer for this scenario.
I have 2 activities: `MainActivity` and `ShellActivity`. `MainActivity` has a navigation drawer and a custom toolbar (`windowActionBar=false`) and will host some top level fragments. `ShellActivity` uses the standard toolbar (`windowActionBar=true`) and will host some lower level fragments like settings and some *detail* type content.

How do I set up the navigation graph for above and how do I navigate from `MainActivity/Fragment1` to `ShellActivity/FragmentB`?

Do I just set each activity up as an independent graph and call it with parameters to load the desired fragment or is there a *proper* way of doing this?

**Why are the activities set up this way?**

Because top level fragments can navigate back and forth directly via the navigation drawer whereas the low level detail fragments should not have access to the navigation drawer (they are secondary destinations and are meaningless without the top level fragment that leads to them). The `ShellActivity` also has `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled=true`, which would conflict with the navigation drawer's operation.

**Update**

1. Setting up the `ShellActivity` as its own graph is impossible because there is no start destination.
2. I've also tried to *toggle* between the navigation drawer and `setDisplayHomeAsUp`, but once I enable the `setDisplayHomeAsUp`, the back arrow clicks are not triggering any callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I just set each activity up as an independent graph and call it with parameters to load the desired fragment or is there a proper way of doing this?

As far as I am concerned -- yes

Anyway your approach doesn't sound right, -- is there anything in your business logic which made you implement navigation this way ? (If it's only about action bar I would suggest to move it to fragments)

Comment: How would moving the Actionbar to the fragments help? The `MainActivity` still has a navigation drawer and its own toolbar. Adding a toolbar to the fragment would give me double toolbars

Comment: Not adding, moving, in your case I would create NavigationDrawerHostFragment (made up name) and move ActionBar there.

Comment: Navigation drawer is connected to the toolbar if `NavigationDrawerHostFragment` has the navigation drawer it has to have the toolbar too. We're back where we started.

Answer (score 0):

How about having just one activity with all the fragments you need? You can update the toolbar when you switch between fragments.